# Can't debug test using breakpoint in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to debug a failing unit test by putting a breakpoint at the beginning of the test method and choosing **Debug Selected Tests** in the Test Explorer. However, the test always runs (and fails) without hitting the breakpoint.

I've tried:

- Cleaning and rebuilding the project
- Restarting Visual Studio

This seems like a pretty basic case - I'm not attaching to a separate process, or doing anything fancy. Just a basic unit test inside VS2013. What else can I try to get the debugger to work correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This did indeed turn out to be simple. I had forgotten that I told Visual Studio not to build the test project (Build - Configuration Manager - unchecked Build). I was trying to speed up my compile times, and it came back to bite me.

Long but simple story short, Build Configuration is another thing you can check if you strangely can't debug code you've placed breakpoints on in the IDE.

Comment: Wasted an hour and a half (hope I could bump into your post a bit earlier), weird though seems like when building manually a new version of assembly in debug but without going through the configuration it does keep up when debugging unit tests.